# Sprindg data repository fails to return DTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring JPA repository that has a method that needs to return result in List of DTO's.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.project.jpa.entity.EmployeeDTO(e.name, r.roleName) FROM Employee e JOIN e.role r")
    List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployee_1();

    @Query("SELECT new EmployeeDTO(e.name, r.roleName) FROM Employee e JOIN e.role r")
    List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployee_2();

    @Query(value = "SELECT new EmployeeDTO(e.name, r.roleName) FROM Employee e JOIN e.role r")
    List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployee_3();

}
```

The three methods that you see above are three variations of what I have tried to get the result. But all three fail and thrown the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.PathNode
```

Am I doing something wrong here.

This is my DTO

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

    private String name;
    private String roleName;

    public EmployeeDTO (String name, String roleName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    /*
        Getters and setters
    */
}
```

Comment: That smells like you have conflicting dependency versions. Post your POM/build file

Comment: Doesn't look like the class EmployeeDTO would compile.

Comment: @EvanJones My bad. Fixed the class

Comment: @chrylis Entity and Repository are in separate modules. I have posted the pom's of both

Comment: It is very uncommon practice to separate the two. I notice that you're using significantly outdated dependencies; is there a reason you're not using the Spring BOM (or better yet, Boot)?

Comment: Its separate because the entities are used at a lot of modules. Also its too late to use boot. Have to stick to current versions as its an old project.

Answer (score -1):

While creating repository class , need to pass same DTO object with identifier of DTO object

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeDTO, Integer> {

//If you need to retrieve all employees then simply try below

```
@Query("FROM EmployeeDTO e")
List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployee_1();
```

//If you need to retrieve employees on specific condition then try below

```
@Query("FROM EmployeeDTO e where e.roleName =:roleName")
List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployeeByRoleName(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```

}